# Cannot read property 'x' of undefined when navigating away from component

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api

My app structure is like this:

Home Page (just where the app starts)

News Page -- makes calls to the WordPress API to generate the list of all the different articles created on the WP backend

Article Page -- rendered dynamically, based on the slug of the URL to query the data for the right article

When I navigate away from the Article Page (to the News Page, or Home Page, or otherwise), I keep getting undefined errors related only to the Article Page component. When I refresh the page that I've navigated away to, the data loads without any problem. That leads me to believe that the Article Page component is still somehow being rendered even when navigating away from the component. How do I prevent this from happening to avoid the undefined errors?

ArticlePage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Article extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      news_articles: [],
      isLoading: true,
      requestFailed: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let newsPath = window.location.pathname;

    // cuts out url before slug
    let newsVariable = newsPath.slice(14);
    let newsURL = `http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=${newsVariable}`;

    // all data
    fetch(newsURL)
    .then(response => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error("Network request failed."); }
          return response.json() })
          .then(d => {
            this.setState({ news_articles:d, isLoading: false }) })
            .catch(() => { 
              this.setState({ requestFailed: true 
              }) 
            }); 
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    let newsPath = window.location.pathname;

    // cuts out url before slug
    let newsVariable = newsPath.slice(14);
    let newsURL = `http://myprivateblogapi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=${newsVariable}`;

    // all data
    fetch(newsURL)
    .then(response => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error("Network request failed."); }
          return response.json() })
          .then(d => {
            this.setState({ news_articles:d, isLoading: false }) })
            .catch(() => { 
              this.setState({ requestFailed: true 
              }) 
            }); 
        }

  render() {

    if(this.state.isLoading) return <div className="light-spinner"><span><i className="fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x"></i></span></div>
    let article_details = this.state.news_articles[0];


  return (

    <div className="full-article--cntr news-article--cntr">

<div className="full-article--full-herospace-cntr">
        <div className="full-article--herospace news-article--herospace icon-page--herospace" 
        style = {
          ( article_details.acf.article_featured_image ) ? 
            ( {backgroundImage: `url(${article_details.acf.article_featured_image})`} ) :
            ( { backgroundColor: "brown" } )
        }>

          <div className="full-article--herospace_text">
          <div className="post-type">
            <div className="red-bar red-bar--above-news"></div>
            <span className="post-type--title">news</span>
          </div>

            <div className="full-article--herospace-info">
              <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article_details.title.rendered }}></h1>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div className="full-article--herospace_overlay">
        </div>
        </div>

        <div className="full-article--content-cntr news-article--content-cntr above-post-it">
          <div className="full-article--content news-article--content">
              <div className="full-article--main" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article_details.content.rendered }} />
              <div className="full-article--meta">
                {/* <div className="author-icon"><img src={article_details._embedded.author['0'].avatar_urls['96']} /></div> */}
                <div className="posted-by"><span>Posted by <span className="red">{article_details.author}</span></span></div>
                <div className="posted-on"><span>{new Date(article_details.date).toString()}</span></div>
              </div>
              </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your Routes? another thing, I would recommend checking for `this.state.new_articles[0] !== undefined` before rendering the whole component based on it... And I would really recommend using a state manager for such an app.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to put that check to make sure it doesn't load if it's undefined. I know there must be another elegant way to do it but for the time restraints, this worked perfectly.